# Is it possible to make JqGrid send a JSON QueryString to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to tell jqGrid to send all search options in JSON format ? Hence I won't have to reformat it on the backend side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct function like that mentioned in the documentation, so you will probably have realize that manually in the beforeSubmit method of the jqGrid. I would spontaneously use [jQuerys serializeArray](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serializeArray) method for the form and a [JSON Serializer](http://www.json.org/js.html). Then you will have to submit the serialized Form via Ajax. Just make sure, that you return success : false, so that jqGrid doesn't submit the form.

```
beforeSubmit : function(postdata, formid) {
    var formarray = $('#' + formid).serializeArray();
    var httpbody = JSON.stringify(formarray);
    // Send accordingly via AJAX
    $.ajax(...);
    // This looks kind of weird, but we don't want jqgrid to continue cause it was sent already
    return { success : false, message : "Successffully saved" };
}
```

Doesn't seem like the nicest sollution though but the beforeSubmit Event is probably the only place to dig into it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how helpful this will be, but I found that I can return true here as long as I set my editurl to '#' ....

beforeSubmit : function(postdata, formid) {

```
                    if (isValid) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            async: false,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            url: "/RateIQ/Main.aspx/Accessorial/AccessorialDetailSave",
                            data: JSON.stringify(postdata),
                            dataType: "json"
                        });
                    }
                    return [isValid, ""];
```

}
and I've experienced no side effects so far...